# Why is try generating an error when there is an except for it to fall back on in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, try-except

I have an issue where try/except is not working in discord.py. It gets an error stating that a user doesn't exist if prompted with a user that does not exist although it should instead send a message stating that said user does not exist.

Code:

```
try:
  if isinstance(member.activity, Spotify):
    await ctx.channel.send(user + ' lyssnar på ' + member.activity.title +
                             ' av ' + member.activity.artist + ' i albumet ' + member.activity.album + '.')
  else:
      await ctx.channel.send(user + ' lyssnar inte på Spotify just nu.')
except:
    await ctx.channel.send(user + ' finns inte.')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 1015, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 932, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 847, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param, attachments)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 709, in transform
    return await run_converters(ctx, converter, argument, param)  # type: ignore
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/converter.py", line 1340, in run_converters
    return await _actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/converter.py", line 1222, in _actual_conversion
    return await converter().convert(ctx, argument)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/converter.py", line 262, in convert
    raise MemberNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "a" not found.
```

Comment: What makes you think that code is raising the exception? Nothing mentioned in the traceback appears in that code.

Answer (score 0):

For catching a discord `MemberNotFound` exception, you can use `on_command_error` to handle this. You can also create a class just for handling different kinds of discord errors. Try something like this:

```py
class Bot_Error_Handler(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
        self.bot: commands.Bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
            await ctx.send("Member not found")
```